# How do I use the value of an attribute within a model? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, models

Basically, I have a model, Degree, and it has three attributes: `degree_type`, `awarded_by`, and `date_awarded`.

There are two arrays of values that should be valid for `awarded_by`. The two valid values for `degree_type` are `"one"` and `"two"`, and the valid values for `awarded_by` depend on `"one"` and `"two"`.

If `degree_type` is `"one"` (has a value of `"one"`, that a user would put in), I want the valid values for `awarded_by` to be `array_one`. If `degree_type` has a value of `"two"`, I want the valid values for `awarded_by` to be `array_two`.

Here is the code so far:

```
class Degree < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend School

  validates :degree_type, presence: true, 
    inclusion: { in: ["one",
                      "two"],
                 message: "is not a valid degree type"
               }

  validates :awarded_by, presence: true,
    inclusion: { in: Degree.schools(awarded_by_type) }
end
```

`Degree.schools` outputs an array depending on the degree type, so `Degree.schools("one")` would return `array_one`, where

```
array_one = ['school01', 'school02'...]
```

My problem is, I don't know how to access the value of `degree_type` within the model.

What I tried below doesn't work:

```
validates :awarded_by, presence: true,
    inclusion: { in: Degree.schools(:degree_type) }
```

I tried using `before_type_cast` but I was either using it incorrectly or there was another problem, as I couldn't get that to work either.

When I test this I get:

> `An object with the method #include? or a proc, lambda or symbol is required, and must be supplied as the :in (or :within) option of the configuration hash`

Help me out? :) If any more info is needed, let me know.

EDIT:  To add to this, I double checked it wasn't my Degree.schools method acting up - if I go into the rails console and try `Degree.schools("one")` or `Degree.schools("two")` I do get the array I should get. :)

EDIT again: When I tried @Jordan's answer, I got errors in the cases where the `awarded_by` was incorrect because in those cases, `valid_awarded_by_values` was `nil` and there is no `include?` method for a nil object. Therefore I added an if statement checking for whether `valid_awarded_by_values` was `nil` or not (so as to `return` if it was), and that solved the problem!

I put this inside the method, before the unless statement and after the valid_awarded_by_values declaration:

```
   if valid_awarded_by_values.nil?
      error_msg = "is not a valid awarded_by"
      errors.add(:awarded_by, error_msg)
      return
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be to write a custom validation method, [as described in the Active Record Validations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods).

In your case, it might look something like this:

```
class Degree < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_awarded_by_inclusion_dependent_on_degree_type

  # ...

  def validate_awarded_by_inclusion_dependent_on_degree_type
    valid_awarded_by_values = Degree.schools(degree_type)

    unless valid_awarded_by_values.include?(awarded_by)
      error_msg = "must be " << valid_awarded_by_values.to_sentence(two_words_connector: ' or ', last_word_connector: ', or ')
      errors.add(:awarded_by, error_msg)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: When I tried to use this, my tests told me:

NoMethodError:
       undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

I'm guessing that whatever value gets put into Degree.schools(degree_type) is not the actual value, which should be a string - do you know how to access that?

(sorry I posted this before finishing it, hit enter too soon)

Comment: Yes, the problem is that `Degree.schools` is returning `nil`. You can write any value to the Rails log with [`logger.debug`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger).

Comment: I figured it out and edited my question - I just had to add an if statement checking for whether Degree.schools was nil to solve the problem. :D Otherwise it appears it was working just fine and I didn't need the exact value after all. :) Thanks so much for the help!